# Подключение к удаленному серверу с Java VisualVM

Tags: java, visualvm

С некоторого времени потребовалось более глубоко анализировать наше enterprise приложение. Я в этом деле полный новичок. Решил использовать VisualVM.
Само приложение стартует на удаленном сервере, на нем точно нет возможности запустить. Скачал VisualVM себе на локальный компьютер и даже смог подключиться к удаленному серверу по ip-шнику. Однако к самому приложению подключиться не могу. Если пытаюсь делать через jmx-подключение, вводя порт приложения, пишет, что "Not supported for this JVM". При попытке наладить подключение через jstatd, не происходит вообще ничего. Что конкретно нужно сделать пошагово, чтобы наладить подключение?
ОС Сервера: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Версия Java сервера: openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~16.04-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: А клиентская версия jdk?

Comment: @Bakhuss java version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.6+8-LTS, mixed mode)

Comment: Может попробуете либо на сервере 11, либо у себя 8-ю поставить?

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка "Not supported for this JVM" значит, что разные версии на сервера и клиента не поддерживаются.

Поставте на клиенте 8-ю версию JDK.